# how to make LM317 output a certain voltage and a certain current

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-design

Ive been looking at a whole bunch of videos about the LM317 voltage regulator and i am just very confused. All i want to do is find a way to output a steady output voltage and a steady output current, lets say 2 Volts and 0.1A. how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Set it for 2V and attach a 20ohm load.

Comment: Like this.. https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=VB40%2fLa0&id=AEBEC2AFCDCAE63E3AC1BB7555A4AC1D114F5A56&thid=OIP.VB40_La0gCZYeOwy-FtFoQEsCj&q=LM317+current+regulator&simid=608018412936694764&selectedIndex=1 but with 12.0R

Comment: The circuit in [this recent physics.se question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369060/22927) will work fine.

Comment: When a power source is connected to a load, they negotiate to find an operating point. A perfect 0.1A current source insists on putting out 0.1A, no matter what. The only thing the load gets to decide is the voltage. A perfect 2V Voltage source insists on putting out 2V, and in that case, the load decides the current. The power source cannot decide both current and voltage. The load has a say in the matter as well.

Comment: A power supply with both voltage and current settings will make sure neither setting is exceeded. It will attempt to put out the set voltage, but depending on the load, it may hit its current limit at a lower voltage. In that case, it will operate as a current source, and not reach the set voltage.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for your laser (so we can be sure it's simply a laser diode and not an integrated module of some kind with its own power supply)?

Comment: Im currently not by my computer anymore but i pulled up this website, https://www.laserdiodesource.com/shop/375nm-70mW-TO-Can-flc this diode requires 5v but on the one i had open on my computer it was 2v at 110mA. This is just to show its a diode and not anything else

Comment: Yes, LEDs are current driven, the voltage is secondary, and if your diode is in spec, the voltage across it will settle at around 2V. But it does not matter,it is the current that is important for LEDs Some laser modules have built in regulators and need a specific voltage range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When driving a laser diode, you want to control the current of your source, and let the laser itself determine the voltage. This current source will work adequately:

[image]

For 100 mA output, you will increase R1 to 12 ohms.

The LM317 is a feedback circuit that increases the voltage at VOUT until there is a 1.25 V difference between VOUT and ADJ. But since the current input to ADJ is very small, nearly all of the current flowing through R1 (Vref / R1) also flows through the load.

The input voltage will need to be at least ~4.25 V above the laser forward voltage for this circuit to provide good regulation.

As shown in the circuit in [your Physics.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369060/22927), it's common to add additional features to provide reverse-battery protection, over-voltage protection, and slow start-up.

Comment: I think i get it now, so if start with a 9v battery i should have enough voltage (because of the heat it creates it loses alot of power) and then i apply my 12ohm resistor as shown in your diagram and then add my diodes and capacitors for extra protection and all that, and i should be good??

Comment: @ReeseHouseknecht, yes.

Comment: @ReeseHouseknecht: Be aware that whatever power the load doesn't need gets turned into heat in the LM317. Make sure you give it a large enough heatsink.